# urllib.request bad magic Error

Tags: python, sublimetext2, urllib

I am trying to fetch webpages using urlib. I am using Python 3.3 and Sublime Text 2 i am facing a problem when i execute the following code

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlopen
remoteaddr = 'http://paulgraham.com/fr.html'
remotefile = urlopen(remoteaddr)
remotedata = remotefile.readlines()
remotefile.close()
for line in remotedata:
    print(line)
```

it produces the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\Documents\Pydev\ftp\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: bad magic number in 'urllib': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

if i run the code with Aptana it executes properly, i would prefer to use ST2 for my dev, any ideas on what the problem might be? I have added ST2 to allowed programs in the firewall.

Comment: Check that your python interpreter between the two are the same. One could be python 2.7 and the other 3.3.

Comment: i have 3.3 only and its set in the %Path% correctly

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: im using Windows 8.1.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the problem but a very likely cause is different versions of python. Are you absolutely sure you don't have another version that may have shipped with Windows 8 pre-installed?

Comment: Sorry I don't use windows for developing and it looks like python has to be manually installed so you are probably correct about only version 3.3 existing. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Do you have a file or directory in the same directory as your `test.py` named `urllib.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your urllib.py is compiled for wrong python version. <strike>Putting away how it was achieved, as urrlib is normal python file, try removing `urllib.pyc` from `Python/lib` folder, and see if it helps.</strike>

**UPDATE**

Putting away was wrong. It got to my mind that Sublime Text 2, althrough entirely not used in your snippet, is working under Python 2 (in fact python 2.6), and its windows package contains compiled urllib within. So it is pretty evident that urllib from Sublime is being imported.

So right course of actions will be  migrate to Sublime Text 3 (beta). Other option might've been downgrading to python 2.6, but judging from python and windows versions, it seems you'll choose to upgrade.

Comment: in the end i ended up resorting to 2.6. as it's mostly what we use in lecture pracs. thanks mate.